# HTTP 415 Requests whilst uploading image

Tags: python, api, python-requests, instagram

I'm trying to upload a image at instagram. But it keeps throwing me 415 HTTPS error. 
I'm not aware of the size requreiment whatsoever. However I'm using requests to make the post request like this.
I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. Under the files dictionary, I have 'data'. Not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Since I couldn't just simply call generateSignature(json.dumps(data)), files=files. It gave me an error so instead I passed in my json under my files.

```
def upload_images(self):
    headers = {'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data;boundary=F77B830B-F788-497D-BBE3-FEEF2A2E0E40','Content-Length':'69452'}
    data = {'_csrftoken':self.LastResponse.cookies['csrftoken'],
            'guid':self.uuid,
            'device_id':self.device_id}
    files = {
        'data':(self.generateSignature(json.dumps(data)),'application/json'),
        'photo': open('first_img.jpg','rb'),
        }


    make_post_requests =self.s.post('https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/upload/photo/',files=files,headers=headers)
    print make_post_requests.text
```

Here is the image information that I'm trying to upload.
[Image information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X5O6.png)

[Here's the image of my HTTPS post request I gained from the sniffer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aREME.png)

I've made everything to work login/comment using valid csrf token and keys. So I'm just stuck at uploading image.

Comment: Is uploading an image allowed?

Comment: They're technically not allowed through browser. But I'm sniffing packets through mitm proxy and figured a way to do so. But looking over at HTTP requests error (415) it has more to do with image itself? I did see about image requirements or something in web but I'm entirely not sure hence I'm here asking for help.

Comment: I'd like to know if there is any news about this, I'm also trying

Comment: @BerkayTutal I got the core to work. I'm just stuck at uploading image. I have no idea why it throws me 415.